# clicking button1 or button2 then clicking button3 to make a panel be visible or not

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, mouseevent

It's supposed to work when I first click either `btn1` or `btn2`, then secondly clicking the `btnFinal`, then the `panelhide` will work.

Below is the one I have been trying to do:

```
Private Sub btnFinal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFinal.Click

    If Me.btn1.Focus() Then
        panelhide.Visible = False
    End If

    If Me.btn2.Focus() Then
        panelhide.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

It should be visible on the output on which button (btn1 or btn2) is highlighted/focused. If-statement is not really necessary if there are other ways for this to work.

It kept focusing on btn2 after clicking btnFinal. I tried ElseIf on btn2 but this time it kept focusing on btn1. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I kind of figured it's on the Focus(), but I might be wrong. Maybe everything's wrong and I would like to apologize in advance. I have been doing the trial-and-error method but this one's I cannot figure out.

Comment: Your code makes little sense as it is. You appear to trying to determine whether `btn1` or `btn2` currently have focus. Firstly, calling the `Focus` method is not the way to do that. Secondly, they can't possibly have focus because that code is only executed when you click `btnFinal`, so `btnFinal` must have focus. You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: It seems bizarre that you'd be making the user click two buttons in the first place. Why not just use two `Buttons` where clicking one hides the `Panel` and clicking the other shows it? You could even just use one `Button` and clicking it toggles the `Visible` property. You could even use a `CheckBox` with the `Apperanance` set to `Button` and then use the `Checked` property to set the `Visible` property.

Comment: If you do want to stick with your current weird UI then you would need to set a field when the user clicks one of the first two `Buttons` and then test that when they click the last `Button`. You would also have to reset that field if the user performed another action in between. The alternative would be to prevent `btnFinal` taking focus when you click it, which is possible but requires a custom class derived from `Button`. I can show you that if you're interested but think carefully whether it's actually what you want.